# Sequence of nested sets in $[0, 1]$ with bound on gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

What is the best possible $\epsilon$ and sequence $(a_n)_{n = 1}^\infty \subset [0, 1]$ we can find such that 
$$
d_{N}:=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\inf_{n=1}^N |x-a_n|\leq \frac{1+\epsilon}{N}
$$
for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$? Note that dyadic decomposition provides $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: I think this is the same as asking for a sequence with lowest possible *discrepancy*, and a search on that term (or a look through the Kuipers & Niederreiter book on uniform distribution of sequences) should turn up some answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me begin by reformulating the question a little bit, making it precise, and also avoiding what happens for the initial finite number of $N$.  Given an infinite sequence $a_n$ in $[0,1]$, for every $N$ let $u_N$ denote the smallest gap between the numbers $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_N$ (when arranged in ascending order between $0$ and $1$) and let $v_N$ denote the maximum gap.  The problem is essentially interested in understanding $v_N/2$ (the point $x$ is halfway between the ends of the maximum gap). The problem as formulated above was studied by A. Ostrowski, [de Bruijn and Erdos](http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00018611.pdf) and also solved (somewhat later) by [Toulmin](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01899983#page-2).  de Bruijn and Erdos (and Toulmin) showed that for any sequence one has 
$$ 
\limsup_{N\to \infty} Nv_N \ge\frac{1}{\log 2} = 1.4426\ldots, 
$$ 
and this value is attained for the sequence 
$$ 
a_n = \{ \log_2 (2n-1)\}, 
$$ 
where $\{ x\}$ stands for fractional part, and $\log_2$ denotes the logarithm to base $2$.  They also show that $\liminf_{N\to \infty} Nu_N$ is always at most $1/\log 4$ and this too is attained in the example above.  You might also find interesting this related recent paper of [Chung and Graham](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/16_01_discrepancy.pdf).

My first thought on seeing the problem was sequences of the form $\{ n\theta\}$ for an irrational $\theta$.  I think that in this class of examples, the golden ratio $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ might be best and gives a normalized largest gap of $\phi^3/\sqrt{5} = 1.8944\ldots$ (if I calculated correctly).  This is not as good as Toulmin's example.  Nevertheless, you might also find interesting this survey of the [three gaps theorem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.501.3023&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (which appeared in L'Enseignement).